# I removed /bin on my Mac, what can I do?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell

```
Last login: Sun Dec 25 08:01:09 on ttys000
login: /bin/bash: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

I opened up my terminal this morning and saw the above message. Not sure how I can get my Mac terminal back?

I was writing a script to `rm -rf /bin` in my current directory, and I'm pretty sure it killed my system bin folder.

Comment: The correct command would be `rm -rf ~/bin`.  Notice the tilde before the `/bin`.

Comment: And that's why you don't run scripts, that only manipulate files you should be owning, as `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got from a quick [google search](http://www.techtalkpoint.com/articles/booting-your-apple-mac-troubleshooting-startup-problems/).

#### Booting From your CD/DVD Drive or External Hard Drive

> Every new mac comes with a Boot CD or Boot DVD for re-installing the operating system (OS) at some time at which the initial install of the OS has reached its sell-by date. This CD is the easiest way to get the machine booted and in a state where you can run some basic tests and fixes using the Apple Disk Utility available as part of the install process.
>
> I am going to make the assumption that you are unable to boot the Mac to a state where you can reach system preferences, so I will disregard the “Startup Disk” selector in a System Preferences as a means by which to select the CD as a boot disk! As an alternative, startup the Mac, as it whirs into action, slot the CD into the drive and then hold down the C key. This will force the Apple Mac to attempt to find a valid system folder on whatever media is contained int he CD/DVD drive and use it to boot the Mac.

Comment: If you quote large parts from another site please at least include the link where it came from.

Comment: True, added the link.

Answer (score 1):

You have successfully deleted your /bin. You can try to copy that directory from another machine or usb stick with the finder (it's only about 40 files). Just don't work as root when trying such things out.

Comment: My computer no longer boots up unfortunately, so I can't copy those files over :(

Comment: @SheehanAlam Do you have your recovery DVDs or, if you're on Lion, just boot up with `Command - R` and recover your system. Or recover from your latest backup.

Comment: I'm on snow leopard, have my DVD, but I can't seem to get it to boot. Tried holding down c, and option key neither work

Comment: You could try a live system to access your harddisk. Check http://www.puredarwin.org/developers/live-cd